# Is map() in javascript synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dictionary, synchronous

Function is :

```
[1,2,3].map( function (item)
{
  console.log(item);
  //return 'something';
});
```

My expected behaviour is getting only 1 as output, unless i uncomment the

```
//return 'something'
```

But i really get

```
1
2
3
```

What am i doing wrong ?

**UPDATE:**

i am testing that with nodejs.

i really dont understand.

```
var async = require("async");

[1,2,3].map( function (item)
{
      console.log(item);
      //return 'something';
}); 
async.map([1,2,3], function (item,callback)
    {
        console.log(item);
        //callback(null,true)
    }, function (err,result)
        {
            console.log(result);
        }
);
```

Both return the same

```
1
2
3
```

And i really would like to wait till i get a return or a callback till the next item is executed.

**SOLVED**

```
async.mapSeries([1,2,3], function (item,callback)
    {
        console.log(item);
        //callback(null,true)
    }, function (err,result)
        {
            console.log(result);
        }
);
```

is the way to do it.

Comment: Why is that your "expected behaviour" ?

Comment: Which browser you are trying this ? for google chrome I am getting the  result as expected in both of the cases.

Comment: Note : map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array.

This is What i got in Google chrome debugger :

[1,2,3].map( function (item)
{
  console.log(item);
  //return 'something';
})
1 VM63:4
2 VM63:4
3 VM63:4
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
[1,2,3].map( function (item)
{
  console.log(item);
  return 'something';
})
1 VM66:4
2 VM66:4
3 VM66:4
["something", "something", "something"]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Yes, map is synchronous.**
It's a higher order function, that takes a new function and applies it to the given array.

Some people think that because they give a function as a parameter to `map` then it 'should' act like an event callback function, but it really doesn't. The `map` function just applies the function parameter to the array and **only after it finishes, it continues execution** for the resulting code after the map block.

As to your 'expected behavior' - it just doesn't work like you think ;)

Answer (score 2):

"The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

The callback is called for each item, your logic is executed and the return value is set as an item in the new array.

Comment: In other words `function map(f,xs){var out=[];for(var i=0;i<xs.length;i++)out.push(f(xs[i]));return out};map(function(x){return x+1},[1,2,3]);//=>[2,3,4]`

Comment: does it mean map() execute those functions in parallel?

Comment: Array.map executes the callbacks synchronously.