# How do I run a function after using array.map?

Tags: node.js

What I'm trying to do is run a function after using array.map. Theoretically, I should be able to just run the after the array.map. However, for some reason, it's running the function before array.map is finished. How do I fix this?

Here's my code.

```
var channelIds = channelNames.map(function (name) {
            request(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=${key}&forUsername=${name}&part=id`, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    var data = JSON.parse(body);

                    if (data.items.length == 0) {
                        callback(`Error: No channel id found for ${name}`);
                    } else {
                        return data.items[0].id;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        function test() {
            console.log(channelIds);
        }

        test();
```

EDIT:

One way which was suggested was to use `async.map`. For some reason, it doesn't want to run the specified callback function like how the documentation says it should.

Here's how I'm doing it now.

```
async.map(channelNames, function (name) {
            request(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=${key}&forUsername=${name}&part=id`, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    var data = JSON.parse(body);

                    if (data.items.length == 0) {
                        callback(`Error: No channel id found for ${name}`);
                    } else {
                        return data.items[0].id;
                    }
                }
            });
        }, function (error, results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
```

Documentation: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map

Comment: The built-in `.map()` method is not designed to support asynchronous operations. It won't wait for the `request()` to complete. – Related: [Is map() in javascript synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629629/is-map-in-javascript-synchronous) and [Use async await with Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map/40140359). – Notable alternative: [`async.map()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map)

Comment: ah. I guess I had it wrong then. Thank you!

Comment: I tried using `async.map()`. For some reason now it's not running the callback function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using Promise.all to resolve all async functions before you call test method?

Try this :

```
const promiseArray = channelNames.map(function (name) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          request(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=${key}&forUsername=${name}&part=id`, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                callback(error); return reject(error);
            } else {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);

                if (data.items.length == 0) {
                    callback(`Error: No channel id found for ${name}`);
                    return reject(`Error: No channel id found for ${name}`);
                } else {
                    return resolve(data.items[0].id);
                }
            }
        });    

  });
});

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(channelIds) {
  console.log(channelIds);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I tried looking into promises before, however, I was pretty confused on how to implement it. Thank you!

Comment: @Bootsie123 however you should remove the line where you are calling "callback" as I don't see what is callback and probably you mistook it while copying...

Comment: There was a bit of code which I didn't show. All of this code is in a separate file from my main code which handles the errors. In that main file when it runs this file it gives it a function which is named callback. Callback is ran if there is an error or once the file has finished running.

Comment: oh, you are fine then... My mistake

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help!