# How to setState after a loop of async functions

Tags: javascript, react-native

The closest answer I could find was this, which didn't help since I need to setState: [How do I run a function after using array.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225897/how-do-i-run-a-function-after-using-array-map)

I think the answer should be simple, but I'm pretty new to Javascript. I'm trying to move the setState for `isLoading` to AFTER I've pulled all of the profiles.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('MatchesScreen init props: ', Object.keys(this.props))

    Object.keys(this.props.profile.profile.matches).map((username) => {
      console.log('match', username)
      url = 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/profile?username=' + username
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
        })
        this.props.addMatch(responseJson)
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      })
    })
  }
```

I've tried various things like appending a `.then()` to the map function, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return each promise inside the `.map()` function, which would leave you with an array of promises. Once you have that, you can use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the promises in the array to resolve.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('MatchesScreen init props: ', Object.keys(this.props))

    // Put all promises into an array
    const promisesArray = Object.keys(this.props.profile.profile.matches).map((username) => {
        console.log('match', username)
        url = 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/profile?username=' + username;
        // Return each promise
        return fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.props.addMatch(responseJson)
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.error(error);
            });
    });

    // Wait for all promises in array to resolve
    Promise.all(promisesArray)
        .then(() => {
            // This will execute once all promises have resolved
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
            });
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```

Comment: Promise.all works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `async`/`await` pattern as follows:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
...
    Object.keys(this.props.profile.profile.matches).map((username) => {
    ...
      await fetch(url, {
      ...
```

then move your `setState` method into its own callback, which you can call in your `.then()` statements following your `fetch`.

I like this reference: https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `Object.keys()` in a while loop with an if statement at the end.

```
var profilesMatched = 0;
while(profilesMatched < Object.keys(this.props.profile.profile.matches).length){
    Object.keys(this.props.profile.profile.matches).map((username) => {
      console.log('match', username)
      url = 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/profile?username=' + username
      fetch(url, { method: 'GET', })
      .then((response) => {response.json()})
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.props.addMatch(responseJson);
        profilesMatched++;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    });
    if(profilesMatched == Object.keys(this.props.profile.profile.matches).length){
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
        })
    }
}
```