# In an Angular service, is it correct to assume the map function is guaranteed to be synchronous if used inside of an Observable?

Tags: angular, dictionary, observable, synchronous

In an Angular app, i have a component that subscribes to an Observable in a service.

```
this.listService.listApi(params)
          .subscribe(
            response => this.listServiceResponse(response),
            error => this.serviceError = <any>error);
```

In the service, the observable makes an http request. I need to loop through the response and construct a results array based on some calculations which will be what is ultimately returned to the component.

For clarity, I have simplified the resulting array here as mine is much more complex, but the point here is that i achieved this using the map function. Here are the relevant parts of the methods in the service:

```
listApi(params:any) Observable<any[]> {
    ...
    return this.http.get(params.url, ampOptions)
                        .map(data => this.listExtract(response, params))
                        .catch(this.handleError);
}
listExtract(response:any, params:any) {

  let successArray:any = [];
  let failedArray:any = [];

  let filteredArray:any = [];

  let itemFound:boolean = false;

  response.map((item, index) => {
    if(item.rank > params.rank) {
      filteredArray.push(item);
      if(item.id === params.id) {
        itemFound = true;
      }
    }
  });

  // are the following lines guaranteed to wait for the map function to finish?

  if(itemFound === true) {

    // do some additional calculations and construct the successArray
    // then push the filteredArray onto my successArray;

    successArray.push(filteredArray);

    return successArray;

  } else {

    // do some additional calculations and construct the failedArray
    // then push the filteredArray onto my failedArray;

    failedArray.push({flag:'failed',id:params.id});
    failedArray.push(filteredArray);

    return failedArray;
  }

}
```

This *appears* to be working correctly, but is it safe to assume that the `map` function is synchronous and the lines that follow are guaranteed to execute only **after** the map function completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `response` is guaranteed to be an array - in order to not blow up your code - then yes, [its map() function is synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629629/is-map-in-javascript-synchronous?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: That link was very helpful in understanding. Thank you!