# How to properly setState when we get info from an array of API's

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a js class in which I'm calling info from the startwars API. I make the response into an object array but when I assign to my State I get an error in my other component(the component is fine when I make the same info that I'm asking from the API static but when I ask from API using fetch I get an error).
Here is what I have tried so far:

STATE--------

```
this.state = {
            data:users
        }
```

---

```
componentDidMount(){
const urls=[
            'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/',
            'https://swapi.co/api/people/2/',
            'https://swapi.co/api/people/3/'
        ]
        const getdata= async function(){
            const people= await Promise.all(urls.map(async function(url){
                const response=await fetch(url);
                return response.json();
            }))
      ---> error causing line     this.setState({data:people})
            console.log("people1",people);



        }}
```

and Second way only trying one of the links---------------------

```
componentDidMount()
    {
 fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(users=>this.setState({data:users}));
    }
```

If I do not use this method the rest of my code works even when I used it with it since this method waits a bit for the component to be mounted I see how the page is in the back then goes to error.

This where the data goes to and give me an error it says data1.map is not a function;

```
const Cardlist= ({data1})=>{
    return(
        <div>
           {data1.map((user,i) => {
        return (
             <Card1 
             name={data1[i].name} 
             homeworld={data1[i].mass+ " lb"}
             />
        );
    })}
        </div>
    );

}
```

Also this is my render

```
  render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <Cardlist data1={this.state.data}/>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

If anyone could just enlighten me that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how asynchronous functions work. In `getData` you are trying to sit into two stools. By calling each people and resolving json at once all of them. But the issue there is no `async map` array method, so you are returning not resolved promise.

 
[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map). 
[More info 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629629/is-map-in-javascript-synchronous).


Here is desirable way.

```js
const getdata= async () => {
 const peoplePromises = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)));
  const people = await Promise.all(peoplePromises.map(promise => promise.json()))
 this.setState({data:people})
 console.log("people1",people);
}
```

Comment: It did not work I got an error which I got earlier as well saying that :
Cannot read property 'SetState' of undefined but when I placed the following api it works
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response=> response.json())
        .then(users=>this.setState({data:users}));
        console.log(this.state);
I know it not the same api but code works somehow maybe I'm not making right arrays

Comment: OK you need arrow function, instead of function definition, editied. Also when you initialize(inside `constructor`) data assign it to empty array.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say yes this worked. Thank you very much